# Getting a text view to take up a whole cell with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to create a table view with cells that each contain a text view that should take up the whole cell and adjust the height of the cell to fit its content. The horizontal and vertical content hugging and compression resistance priorities are set accordingly.

I have set up the cells to have automatic height

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

In my `cellForRowAt...` I create constraints for the top, leading, trailing, and bottom edges of the text view, constraining it within the content view of the cell.

The problem is that at runtime the text view doesn't take up multiple lines and grow the size of the cell. It instead runs off the trailing edge of the cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let entry = server.log[indexPath.row]
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.isEditable = false
    //textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.text = entry.message
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.contentView.addSubview(textView)

    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .bottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    //top.priority = 999
    //leading.priority = 999
    trailing.priority = 999
    bottom.priority = 999

    cell.contentView.addConstraints([top, bottom, leading, trailing])

    textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, for: .horizontal)
    textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, for: .vertical)
    textView.setContentHuggingPriority(1001, for: .horizontal)
    textView.setContentHuggingPriority(1001, for: .vertical)

    return cell;
}
```

### How the cells appear at runtime

[image: How the cells appear at runtime]

### How the frames appear

[image: How the frames appear]

### What the view hierarchy debugger reports

[image: What the view hierarchy debugger reports]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1)

> For example, if there are no returns in the text, it calculates the
>   height and width needed to layout the content as a single line of
>   text. If you add constraints to specify the view’s width, the
>   intrinsic content size defines the height required to display the text
>   given its width.

Given this, the solution that uses the intrinsic content size is setting a constraint for a constant width. I also opted for using `UILabel`, but this applies to `UITextView` too.

```
let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: cell.contentView.frame.width - cell.contentView.layoutMargins.left - cell.contentView.layoutMargins.right)
```

For my particular situation, I also needed to set the priority of the bottom constraint to `500` and set the vertical content compression resistance to `UILayoutPriorityRequired`.

Answer (score 1):

No where in your code are you setting the height for your `UITextView` (or it's frame for that matter). This means that the textView will have a calculated frame based on the constraints you have provided. You might want to add a `height` constraint for your textView and see if that works.

Comment: It already has one due to the intrinsic content size of the text view (`self.height = 30 @ 1000 (content size)`, see the last screenshot). The point of this question is how to get it to expand vertically automatically as necessary using the intrinsic content size. It has to do with content compression and hugging.

Comment: You will still need to set the height constraint for that matter.  It would be something like `textViewHeightConstraint.constant = textView.intrinsicContentSize.height`

Comment: `textView.intrinsicContentSize.height` is 30. Doing `NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: textView.intrinsicContentSize.height)` results in a constraint that is identical to the one automatically created that I mentioned in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would change your UITextView to a UITextField.
Then you can do this in code:

```
    let example = UITextField()
    example.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    example.numberOfLines = 0
```

In interface builder just change the .numberOfLines to 0 for the text view.

Comment: Those are both `UILabel` properties.

Comment: They are also uitextview properties. Look at UITextField.h in the UIKit: @property(nonatomic)        BOOL                    adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth; @property(nonatomic)        BOOL                    adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth; // default is NO. if YES, text will shrink to minFontSize along baseline

Comment: Thanks ahyattdev, my fingers and brain were not in synch. I meant UITextField.